# Create an object in Javascript and animiate it

Tags: javascript, animation

I'd like to create objects in Javascript and have them be able to animate themselves, i.e. not in an external animation function driving them.

```
<script>
const Canvas = document.getElementById("diagramCanvas");
const CanvasContext = Canvas.getContext('2d');
const width = Canvas.width, height = Canvas.height;

var cmTID;
function SelfMovingBox() {
    this.x = width;

    this.animate = function() {
        CanvasContext.clearRect(this.x,10,100,20);
        this.x -= 10;
        CanvasContext.save();
        CanvasContext.strokeStyle = 'blue';
        CanvasContext.strokeRect(this.x,10,100,20);
        CanvasContext.restore();
        setTimeout(this.animate, 100);
    }


}

let box = new SelfMovingBox();
box.animate();

</script>
```

But this "loop" will not run more than once. Why does it terinate with no error, and how could I achieve this, without a this.move() function in the object invoked externally in an animation function loop?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a problem with the use of `this`.

Looking at just the relevant parts:

```
function SelfMovingBox() {
    this.x = width;
    this.animate = function() {
        this.x -= 10;
    }
}
```

When you set `this.x = width`, `this` refers to the `SelfMovingBox` instance, because you are calling the function with `new`.

But in `animate`, `this` is referring to `Window`, which is JavaScript's default (weird) behavior for functions.

You have a few options: use an arrow function `() => {}` for lexically scoped `this`:

```
this.animate = () => {
  this.x -= 10;
}
```

or use `bind` to explicitly bind `this`:

```
this.animate = (function() {
  this.x -= 10;
}).bind(this);
```

Comment: Thanks BRANDON! By the way, Will I have any difficulties with Javascripts one-thread rendering when I create, lets say, 10 moving boxes at one time, aniated this way?

Comment: Rendering 10 boxes at a time should be no problem.

Comment: However, I would not recommend using `setInterval` for animation, and having objects be responsible for their own animation. Typically you use an external function so that all the animations can be kept in sync. With `setInterval`, the animations will go out of sync.

I would recommend re-thinking your design by using `requestAnimationFrame`, and animating all 10 objects at once (possibly keeping a list of which objects "need" to be animated, if you are worried about unnecessary CPU overhead). To figure out how much time has elapsed between frames, use something like `window.performance.now`

Comment: All super helpful suggestions. I'll follow up on these now.. Thanks, Brandon